# Error con FOR en public class

Tags: c#, array, xamarin, recyclerview, xamarin.android

Tengo una clase que me sirve para llenar dinámicamente un RecyclerView, el problema es que actualmente lo lleno "manualmente" (indizandolo uno a uno, ya se imaginaran los inconvenientes de eso) y necesito llenarlo con un For (segun los resultados que me devuelva la API) pero no se como hacerlo ya que al no ser un `Void` me dice que está fuera de contexto.

Adjunto Clase:

```
public class PhotoAlbum
        {
            public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos =
            {                
                //Agregar For (Me da error)
                //for (Globales.pN=0; Globales.pN < Globales.CantidadMax; Globales.pN++)

                new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[Globales.pN], mCaption = Globales.NombreList[Globales.pN] },

                //Originalmente:
                //new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[0], mCaption = Globales.NombreList[0] },
                //new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[1], mCaption = Globales.NombreList[1] },
                //new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[2], mCaption = Globales.NombreList[2] },
                // etc..............

            };
```

Ideas por favor?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás intentando hacer el `for` dentro del constructor del array de `Photos`, y eso no es posible, ya que eso solo se usa para añadir valores al array, no para hacer otras operaciones.

Para hacer lo que comentas deberías implementar una función específica para realizar esa acción, por ejemplo:

```
public class PhotoAlbum
{
    public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos = new Photo[]();

    public void LlenarPhotos()
    {
        for (Globales.pN=0; Globales.pN < Globales.CantidadMax; Globales.pN++)
        {
            mBuiltInPhotos[Globales.pN] = new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[Globales.pN], mCaption = Globales.NombreList[Globales.pN] };
        }
    }
}
```

Para llamar la función simplemente deberias hacer lo siguiente en cualquier sitio:

```
PhotoAlbum pa = new PhotoAlbum()
pa.LlenarPhotos();
```

Y llamas la lista:

```
pa.mBuiltInPhotos
```

Comment: Si hago eso me dice que `mBuiltInPhotos` no existe en el contexto actual. Donde lo tendria que crear el Void?

Comment: @KennyAli He editado mi respuesta, pero basicamente eso seria una función de la clase o en cualquier otro sitio, pasandole la variable del array de photos.

Answer (score 1):

Si la variable `Globales` es una lista podrias usar `foreach`

```
public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos 
{                
    get
    {
        List<Photo> photos = new List<Photo>();
        
        foreach (var g in Globales)
        {
            var p = new Photo { mPhotoID = g.ImagenesList[g.pN], mCaption = g.NombreList[g.pN] };
            photos.Add(p);
        }
        
        return p.ToArray();
    }

}
```

No tienes que incrementar una variable que sea parte del objeto que estas iterando, en este caso `pN`, si lo necesitas crear una variable auxiliar

Imagine quisiste crear una `propiedad` con al estructura

```
public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos 
{                
    get {...}
}
```

pero si es una `funcion` seria

```
public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos()
{                
    ...
}
```

Comment: Me da lo mismo que si intento hacer el FOR, no lo reconoce y me dice que `get` no existe en el contexto actual y me marca todo como error. Me dices si te sirve una imagen del error.